# Machine Learning/Neural Network JS library for "Aaronson Oracle" project?

Tags: python, javascript

For reference, this is an example of an [Aaronson Oracle](https://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/%7Enick/aaronson-oracle/).

I'm planning to incorporate this into a discord bot, and currently have a discord bot set up using discord.js.

I have some experience with tensorflow, but only from online classes so I've got a mostly superficial level of how the code works.

I'm not sure if there's a JavaScript library already available that I could use instead, because that would be preferable because of the easy compatibility with my already set up discord bot using js. But Python would be an alright alternate since that's the other commonly used method for setting up discord bots, and hypothetically better suited to this since I know there is more likely tensorflow code/training models using python.

If there is a tensorflow python library you recommend, how hard would you rate the learning curve for a beginner who knows just the barest basics of both?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [the program you already linked to](https://github.com/elsehow/aaronson-oracle)? It's in JavaScript and doesn't require a neural network. It just uses a moving average.

Comment: I'm looking for a neural network/machine learning library because I want to be able to try applying the same idea but in a different method.